# How to access an 'outside' variable in a class func in swift?

Tags: swift

I have declared a class function in Swift and I wish to be able to access a certain variable in this function which has been declared outside.

```
var something : Int = 0
```

and

```
class func add()
{
}
```

So I wish to access the value of 'something' in this class func.

Sorry if I sound stupid, still a bit new to Swift so please bear with me.

Comment: Declare the var as a class variable, `var something ...`. Then access it using `MyClass.something`, where `MyClass is your class name.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should understand what is class func, this is kind of the same as static func with a small difference with overriding rules.

if you want to access `var something : Int` you need to create an **instance** of that class.

```
var classInstance = MyClass() //swift allocates memory and creates an instance
classInstance.something = 5
```

static variable is a global variable, that can be accessed without creating an instance.

```
static var something : Int = 4
MyClass.something = 3 //didnt create instance of MyClass
```

you have to set the value to a static variable when declaring it (or setting a nil as optional)

```
static var something : int //this will not compile
```